# How do I use commands in Slime Rancher? (specifically spawning the Rad slime)

Tags: slime-rancher

How do I use commands in slime rancher? Please explain how to spawn a rad slime.

Answer (score 2):

As described by a user that is now deleted on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/slimerancher/comments/3yo08g/green_slimes_are_in_the_game_files_just_not/)

> First of all back up your Assembly-Csharp.dll, if anything goes wrong
>   you can just restore that file and try again or play the game as
>   normal :)
>
> - open the assembly in a modification tool (i used dotnetresolver)
> - find the "{}" section and expand it
> - find the "debugDirector" section and expand that too
> - click on the "Update(): Void" item inside there
> - heres where it gets tricky, in the MSIL editor tab to the right nop the lines that correspond to the "if(debug.isDebugBuild)" I don't
>     have those lines in my file anymore so I can't tell you what it looks
>     like in MSIL without re-downloading the game
>
> (to nop a line highlight it inside the MSIL editor, right click and
>   select "Nop Instruction(s)", my lines are already nop'd but this
>   screenshot should get across the general idea
>
> If all went correctly the MSIL editor should look something like this
>   with the "System.Single UnityEngine.Time::get_timeScale()" being the
>   first untouched line
>
> For anyone curious what this is doing its actually removing the
>   condition that these keybinds are only active during the debug edition
>   of the game, after making these modifications the debug keybinds will
>   be active in any version of the game
>
> If you made it this far all you have to do is save the file and open
>   the game, the keybinds are listed inside the code but i'll list them
>   here just incase you have trouble reading them.
>
> - [ = decrement time of day
> - ] = increment time of day
> - + = Add 1000 Credits
> - - = Remove 1000 Credits
> - F6 = Toggle HUD
> - F12 = Reset Achievement Progress
>
> (The numbers below refer to the keys above the letters on the
>   keyboard, I don't think the numpad keys will work)
>
> - 0 = Award all personal upgrades (jetpack, energy etc)
> - 7 = Force Save
> - 9 = Fill Vacpack with random items/ammo (this is how i got the green
>     slimes)

I will sit down and follow these instructions myself in a few days and try and simplify this content.